# How to view full PDF files in Power BI RS (other than PDFViewer visual)?

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

Knowing that we have on-prem Power BI Server and our company restricts data and restricts going out of their network to view the data. I'm trying to view PDF files in a Power BI Report.

I've used PDFViewer and connected to SQL DB and it works, however, it doesn't provide **scrolling option**.
is there a way to load the files to the PBI Server and load it in the report?
Or I just need a way to load and view the PDFs and scroll through them within Power BI knowing the limitations and restrictions I mentioned at the beginning.

Thanks!